# Como centrar dos textos en Flutter

Tags: flutter

tengo el siguiente Widget:

```
class PoinstsDisplayState extends State<PoinstsDisplay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: new Text(
        '5000 Pts',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontFamily: 'Karla'
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Este se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal cual se ve esta perfecto, sin embargo ahora necesito darle estilos al numero de manera independiente del texto 'Pts', para esto necesito tener 2 `Text`'s centrados de manera que se vean exactamente igual que en la imagen, lo cual no he logrado hacer, he intentado con `Row`, mas `Container`'s, la clase `Center`, etc y no lo he conseguido.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el caso de textos en una línea con diferentes estilos puedes hacerlo de una forma más sencilla usando el `RichText` widget, mira como quedaría:

```
        Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: '5000 ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0, fontFamily: 'Karla'),
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text: 'Pts',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Karla')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Así le puedes aplicar diferentes estilos a cada `TextSpan`.

Puedes encontrar más info aquí : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html